# Analyzing windows event logs on another windows system with less event publishers

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, event-log

When analyzing saved event logs from another PC, one may see the following instead of an event description:

"The description for Event ID [] from source [] cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event."

Wevtutil.exe, as well as manual export from the event viewer, provides the option to save event descriptions in LocaleMetaData folder. `Wevtutil al /?` gives us the following explanation:

"Archive log file in a self-contained format. A subdirectory with the name
of the locale is created and all locale-specific information is saved in
that subdirectory. When the directory created by the archive-log command is
present along with the log file, **events in the file can be read whether or
not the publisher is installed**."

The question is: how to attach these exported descriptions and see them when looking through foreign event logs with event viewer on another machine where some publishers aren't installed? I've never succeeded in this and I could not find any hints or success stories.
Sometimes they say that it's absolutely necessary to have the same product installed on the analyzing machine to see readable descriptions of events generated by this product. This statement seems to contradict to the bold fragment above, doesn't it?

Comment: If you can connect remotely, you might try Nirsoft's FullEventLogView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html , which allows saving the logs as a file. It also makes searching easier.

Comment: Thanks for this useful tool but in this very environment I cannot use it...